# JAVA_HOME issue when running Sqoop command

Tags: java, sqoop, cloudera-cdh

I am trying to use sqoop for importing the data from oracle. I am following the tutorial  using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16101967/it-seems-as-though-you-are-running-sqoop-with-a-jre-but-java-home-set-to-jdk). I am getting an error as:

> JAVA_HOME is not set.

But when I type   `echo $JAVA_HOME`, I get the path where it is set. But running following sqoop command gives an error:

```
sudo bin/sqoop import –connect jdbc:oracle:thin:system/

system@192.168.46.1:1521:xe

–username system -P –table system.emp –columns “ID” –target-dir /

sqoopoutput1 -m 1
```

Comment: what is the value of JAVA_HOME? eventually what does the `which java` command return? 32Bit vs. 64Bit

Comment: When I do echo $JAVA_HOME then I get output as /usr/java/jdk version.

Comment: try setting $JAVA_HOME as /usr/java/jdk/bin

Comment: ok Thanks will do that.